# Issue with opening and moving new window with AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I have 2 monitors and an AppleScript to open a new Chrome window and move it to a specific position on the left monitor.

If I already have a full screen Chrome window on the right monitor and then run the below script, the new window opened by the script would always be opened in full screen on the right. I added the if statement to exit the full screen mode for the newly opened window (so that `set position` can work) when this happens.

The problem is that the original full screen window (the one that was already there) would then be hidden in a different space and that I have to find it back from Mission Control.

Is there a way to bring the original full screen window back or simply have the script open the new window on the left directly (without having open -> exit full screen -> set position)?

Thank you.

Code:

```applescript
on isRunning(appName)
    tell application "System Events" to (name of processes) contains appName
end isRunning

if isRunning("Google Chrome") then
    tell application "Google Chrome" to make new window
else
    tell application "Google Chrome" to activate
end if

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Google Chrome"
        
        # Exit full screen if new window is opened in full screen mode
        if value of attribute "AXFullScreen" of window 1 is true then
            repeat until (value of attribute "AXFullScreen" of window 1 is false)
                set value of attribute "AXFullScreen" of window 1 to false
                delay 1
            end repeat
        end if
        
        # Move and resize new window
        set position of window 1 to {0, 0}
        set size of window 1 to {1280, 800}
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Don't use chrome but with the chromium-based Vivaldi, you can `make new window with properties {bounds:{50, 50, 800, 700}}` and for me it works even when there is a full-screen window. Might be an option in Chrome as well.

Comment: @Mockman Thanks! `tell application "Google Chrome" to make new window with properties {bounds:{0, 25, 1280, 800}}` seems working!

Comment: Update: the problem persists with the above change with Chrome :(

Comment: Which problem? The re-spaced full screen 'window'? Alas, that is a separate issue which will likely always occur when you have one window full screen. You could probably script the mission control action (using UI scripting).

Comment: yes exactly that problem. I'll look into it, thanks!